# Get file modification date?

Tags: python, file

I use the following code to get modification date of file if it exists:

```
if os.path.isfile(file_name):
    last_modified_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_name))
else:
    last_modified_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
```

Is there a more elegant/short way?

Comment: I believe this answers your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could use exception handling; no need to first test if the file is there, just catch the exception if it is not:

```
try:
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(file_name)
except OSError:
    mtime = 0
last_modified_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime)
```

This is asking for forgiveness rather than permission.